# Scheduling actions

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I'm making a BlackJack application using Kivy, I basically need to make a sort of `delay` or even a `time.sleep`, but of course, it doesn't have to freeze the program. I saw kivy has `Clock.whatever` to schedule certain actions. What I'd like to do is scheduling multiple actions so that when the first action has finished, the second will be run and so on. What's the best way to achive this? or is there in the Clock module something to perform multiple delays one after another?

This could be an example of what i need to do:

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix import BoxLayout
from functools import partial

class Foo(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        for index_time, card in enumerate(cards, 1):
            # Schedule this action to be run after 1 sec from the previous one and so on
            Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.function, card), index_time)

    def function(self, card, *args):
        self.add_widget(card)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm surprised that your question didn't get down-voted since this is not supposed to be a place for opinion questions. So you shouldn't ask for `best`.

The `Clock` module doesn't have a specific method to do what you want. Obvioulsy, you could do a list of `Clock.schedule_once()` calls, as your example code does. Another way is to have each function schedule its successor, but that assumes that the functions will always be called in that order.

Anyway, there are many ways to do what you want. I have used a construct like the following:

```
class MyScheduler(Thread):
    def __init__(self, funcsList=None, argsList=None, delaysList=None):
        super(MyScheduler, self).__init__()
        self.funcs = funcsList
        self.delays = delaysList
        self.args = argsList


    def run(self):
        theLock = threading.Lock()
        for i in range(len(self.funcs)):
            sleep(self.delays[i])
            Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.funcs[i], *self.args[i], theLock))
            theLock.acquire()
```

It is a separate thread, so you don't have to worry about freezing your gui. You pass it a list of functions to be executed, a list of arguments for those functions, and a list of delays (for a sleep before each function is executed). Note that using `Clock.schedule_once()` schedules the execution on the main thread, and not all functions need to be executed on the main thread. The functions must allow for an argument that is a `Lock` object and the functions must release the `Lock` when it completes. Something like:

```
def function2(self, card1, card2, theLock=None, *args):
    print('in function2, card1 = ' + str(card1) + ', card2 = ' + str(card2))
    if theLock is not None:
        theLock.release()
```

The `MyScheduler` class `__init__()` method could use more checking to make sure it won't throw an exception when it is run.